# Imgproc.cvtColor parameters meaning

Tags: java, opencv

What is the meaning of parameter `4` in the following function?

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(pointMatHsv, pointMatRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(pointMatHsv, pointMatRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL, 4);
```

4 is the number of channels in the destination image.

If the parameter is 0, the number of the channels is derived automatically from src and code .

```
cvtColor Converts an image from one color space to another.
```

Syntax

```
cvtColor(Mat src, Mat dst, int code, int dstCn)
```

More info [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html)